# Does DDR4 RAM with ECC give a significant advantage over regular DDR4 RAM with its CRC?

Tags: memory, ecc

Standard DIMMs before DDR4 had no error checking and the common practice for HA servers or workstations with increased RAM was the use of DIMMs with ECC.

The DDR4 standard introduced CRC checking for non-ECC modules.

Has this somewhat closed the safety gap between regular and ECC RAM or is ECC still advised from a certain amount of RAM even in workstations?

Comment: May be f you are willing to pay the price. ECC works in hardware directly on the module. If the CPU performs the CRC checking it costs you memory capacity, bandwidth and may be even CPU usage depending how the CRC check is performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECC stands for Error Checking and Correcting,
while CRC stands for Cyclic Redundancy Check error detecting.

ECC provides stronger protection against soft errors by correcting simple errors
such as a single-bit dead.

In short, CRC will only detect a RAM error, but ECC may succeed in correcting it
for small errors.

For consumer devices there may not be a large difference between the two types,
because bad RAM needs to always be replaced. But for mission-critical devices, ECC
can extend their useful lifetime.

See Wikipedia
[Error detection and correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction).

Comment: DDR4's CRC also only protects data transmission, not data in memory.

Comment: The following article was also helpful to answer my question: https://www.quora.com/When-does-ECC-RAM-make-sense-What-are-the-differences-to-normal-RAM